# Wordpress 404 in development area

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error

I have a live WP site, which I have taken a copy of and put onto a new server for testing / development.

Once I put the website on the new area I updated the site url and home url in the database, ensured the .htaccess file was showing correctly and everything in the wp-config was correct.

When I try and access a page which is not the **Home Page** or **wp-admin area** I get a 404 error.

I have tried resaving the permalinks, ensuring all urls in the database are the new servers ip's  , and disabling each plugin one by one to see if there was any conflicts but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I am missing / any advice.

Thank you

Comment: Are `.htaccess` _overrides_ and mod_rewrite enabled on the new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrWhite mentioned above, mod_rewrite was not enabled on the new server. Enabled that and all is working fine now.

Thanks for your help